# how to make a switch

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main2 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a=scan.nextInt();
            int b=1;
            for (int i=1;i<=30;i++){
                if(i%a==0){
                    b=1;
                    System.out.print("X");
                }else {
                    System.out.print("O");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- I drive 3 into the scanner
- the desired result
- XXXOOOXXXOOOXXXOOOXXX

Comment: what do you mean "how to make switch" ?

Comment: I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
            if (i%a==0) {
                b = 1-b;
            }
            if(b==1){
                System.out.print("X");
            }else {
                System.out.print("O");
            }
```

UPDATE: with a `switch` statement:

```
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            if (i%a==0) {
                b = 1-b;
            }
            switch (b) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.print("O");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("X");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: XXOOOXXXOOOXXXOOOXXXOOOXXXOOOX

Comment: Change the `for` loop: `for (int i=0; i<30; i++){`

Comment: It's the statement: `b = 1-b;`

Comment: You could also write: `b = (b+1)%2;`

Comment: If you want a `switch` statement (and not just switch the value of `b`), see my update.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your code, there is no need for a switch. I got the desired output by use of nested for loops.

```
int XPerGroup = 3 ;
    int group = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < group; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < XPerGroup; j++) {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

You can just change hardset variables into scanner input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).